# How to count rows in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find whether a person (id = A3) is continuously active in a program at least five months or more in a given year (2013). Any suggestion would be appreciated. My data look like as follows:

[image]

Comment: how your data looks like? have you forgotten to add this in the question?

Comment: What do you mean by continuously?

Comment: Hi Gordon, continuously meaning without month gap for at least five months.

Answer (score 2):

You simply use `group by` and a conditional expression:

```
select id,
       (case when count(ActiveMonthYear) >= 5 then 'YES!' else 'NAW' end)
from table t
where ListOfTheMonths between '201301' and '201312'
group by id;
```

EDIT:

I suppose "continuously" doesn't just mean any five months.  For that, there are various ways.  I like the difference of row numbers approach

```
select distinct id
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by id order by ListOfTheMonths) -
              count(ActiveMonthYear) over (partition by id order by ListOfTheMonths)
             ) as grp
      from table t
      where ListOfTheMonths between '201301' and '201312'
     ) t
where ActiveMonthYear is not null
group by id, grp
having count(*) >= 5;
```

The difference in the subquery is constant for groups of consecutive active months.  This is then used a grouping.  The result is a list of all ids that meet this criteria.  You can add a `where` for a particular id (do it in the subquery).

By the way, this is written using `select distinct` and `group by`.  This is one of the rare cases where these two are appropriately used together.  A single `id` could have two periods of five months in the same year.  There is no reason to include that person twice in the result set.

Comment: @Gordon..is the order not important here?

Comment: This is probably the right answer. However I thought. Perhaps user needs to log in for straight 5 months?

Comment: @vkp . . . I misunderstood the problem when I first answered it.